Enforcing Time Constraint
Given
create table statement_requests(
   id   INT PRIMARY KEY, 
   year INT NOT NULL, 
   requested_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);

This table captures requests for a "statement." A user may request a statement for a single year once every 24 hours. So if a user has requested a year 2023 statement on Jan-1-2024 at 1 PM, he must wait 24 hours to request another 2023 statement.
What can I add to ensure that, at most, one row is allowed per year for every 24 hours?
Initially I tried a DEFERRED CONSTRAINT, but learned via https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/ that that won't work.
Given:
(1, 2024, '2024-11-18 15:00:00.000-05')

the following is allowed to be inserted:
(2, 2024, '2024-11-19 15:01:00.000-05'

but
(3, 2024, '2024-11-18 15:00:00.001-05')

is not.

Using the btree_gist extension you can create an exclusion constraint.
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE statement_requests 
    ADD CONSTRAINT per_year_24h_limit
    EXCLUDE USING gist (
        year with =,
        tsrange(
            requested_at AT TIME ZONE 'GMT',
            requested_at AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' + interval '24' hour
            ) WITH &&
    );

All that "AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'" is needed to keep postgresql happy.
because timestamptz + inverval does not give an immutable result
so I have to convert to timestamp.
In this case the result is entirely predictable but it's simpler to convert to timestamp than to create a new add seconds to timestamptz operator.
